Why is a Promise.reject returned in an async function not caught by a try-catch block inside that function?
I'm implementing an asynchronous function to fetch and show JSON data from an API.
In order to handle errors properly, I'm using a try/catch block.
But I'm getting an "Uncaught (in promise)" Error - and I don't understand why.
This is my code:
const getData = async() => {
  const url = "https://dummyjson.com/quotees?limit=20"; // it contains a typo (quotees) intentionally
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    return res.ok ? res.json() : Promise.reject(res.status);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

getData()
  .then(d => {
    if (d) d.quotes.forEach(q => ...);
  });

The output of console.log(err) is "Uncaught (in promise) 404".
Why isn't it simply "404"?

You don't handle the rejection coming from the Promise.reject(res.status) from inside getData. That is unhandled. In fact, the try/catch in the function doesn't even do much.

Is there a way to handle the Promise rejection inside the try/catch block?

...You are producing the promise rejection in the try/catch. If you don't want to do that, then don't.

I need to produce the Promise rejection in order to show a custom error message in the catch block, according to the res.status.

The promise rejection is the result of the getDat() function. You're asking how to handle the result of getData() before finishing getData(). Which is impossible - it's a chicken and egg problem. Either you don't reject and just handle that case inside the function, or you reject from inside and then handle that at the call site. You don't try to do both. Consider the synchronous example - you're asking "How can I throw an exception but not throw an exception and handle it but also throw the exception. Because I need it thrown"

It is not the Promise in an async function that will cause the code of the catch block to be executed, it is the await keyword. And already being in an async function you would use throw res.status instead of Promise.reject(res.status)

@t.niese This is a useful suggestion. Thanks. I'm new to async functions.

@t.niese you could use throw but from everything OP has said, you shouldn't. The only interpretation I can get is that they want to not produce an error. throw inside the try to go to the catch is possible but usually considered an anti-pattern. If you know something is a problem, you don't have to throw considering you also want to immediately handle it.

@VLAZ If I understood correctly, you would handle any errors inside the try block directly, without throwing them at all. Am I right?

@AbsoluteBeginner most likely that is what you want to do. As I said, I find it hard to follow, since you said you don't want to reject...but you also have to reject. And asking how to reject but also handle the rejection. You could handle it immediately which is most likely what should happen (then there is no further problems to take care of). Maybe you want t set an error flag to handle both throws from fetch and not ok things the same way (presumably handling that takes more than one line of code and should be uniform). Or possibly call some error handling function.

Or maybe you do actually want to handle this at the call site. You already kind of do with the if (d) which seems to be there to "protect" against the error handling.

@VLAZ I fully agree with that. I didn’t want to say that the OP should use the throw in a try block or for control flow, what I wanted to say is that if one is already in an async function then using Promise.reject(err) in there is not what you want to do but throw err. If to use throw or not is then identical to any other situation.

Re melius perpensa, I think in my case there's no reason to throw any errors, because I can handle them in the try/block directly. I'm happy I fed a discussion on this issue, which I think is of interest to many people. So I really don't understand the negative vote on my question.

@AbsoluteBeginner I didn't cast any vote, but the negative could be because there are various questions about that topic like Why a promise reject is not catched within a try catch block but produces an Uncaught error? and Why is a promise rejection within a loop not handled in a try catch in JS? (Didn't do an exhaustive search). But casting a downvote without giving a reason is devinitily annoying.

@VLAZ, "In fact, the try/catch in the function doesn't even do much." - is it because the fetch didn't reject, thereby preventing the catch block from executing?

@NapoleonBonaparte because it only goes to the catch if the fetch rejects. Doesn't activate if there is just any rejection anywhere. And that rejection is not await-ed as is the case in the code here.

@VLAZ, So I am correct then.

You return a rejected promise which is unhandled thus raising an error at the global scope. To use your catch block just throw:


const getData = async() => {
  const url = "https://dummyjson.com/quotees?limit=20"; // it contains a typo (quotees) intentionally
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    if(res.ok) return res.json();
    throw res;
  } catch(err) {
    if(err instanceof Response){
      console.log('response error:', err.status);
    } else {
      console.log('another error:', err);
    }
  }
};

getData();




Are exceptions as control flow considered a serious antipattern? If so, Why?

@VLAZ the scope is very small, don't see a big flaw here. if you provide a better example where in catch we display for example a common error toast, i'd appriciate

Sorry, I can't provide you with good examples of using exceptions as flow control.

I think you can throw the rejected promise and add a catch block to handle it.
Something like the following should work -
const getData = async() => {
  const url = "https://dummyjson.com/quotees?limit=20"; 
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(res.status);  
    }
    return res.json();
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);  
};

getData()
  .then(d => {
    if (d) d.quotes.forEach(q => ...);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // error handling
  });


Are exceptions as control flow considered a serious antipattern? If so, Why?
